# $X$ being locally closed is not equivalent to every extension by $0$ of a sheaf $F$ being unique?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

In Tennison's book "Sheaf Theory", the author presents a proof that there is a unique extension by $0$ for a sheaf $F$ over $X$ iff $X \subset Y$ is locally closed . However, apparently in the proof of the "if" part, he uses that some neighborhood of a given point is connected, therefore the proof is wrong. I would like to know if this fact is indeed correct.

I think that this theorem is not true, because picking $Y = \mathbb{R}^2$ and $X$ equals an open disk, then the sheaf $\mathbb{Z}_X$ can be extended to the whole plane by picking the sheaffication of $F (U) =\mathbb{Z}$ if $U \subset X$ and $F = 0$ otherwise, then each stalk lying out of the disk is zero. Furthermore any other sheaf  extending by $0$ $\mathbb{Z}_X$ (apparently) will be isomorphic to this one. But $D = X$ is open , hence not locally closed!!!! Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An open subset of a space **is** locally closed (and putting four exclamation marks after the negation of this statement, as you did, won't alter the facts...)

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Ops, you're right. However, is the statement correct (the "if" part)?

Comment: Yes, the statement is correct. I don't see any allusion to a connected neighbourhood of a point in Tennison's proof: where did you see that?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg In the part "...by shrinking U we can ensure that for all $x' \in U \cap X, s(x')= 1$ " it does not hold for a totally disconnected space.

Comment: Yes Tennison's assertion  holds for a totally disconnected space or any topological space whatsoever: given a topological space $X$ and an open neighbourhood  $V\subset X$ of some point $x\in X$,  any section $s\in \Gamma(V,\mathbb Z_X)$  with $s(x)=1$ has the property that $s(x')=1$ for $x'$ in some neighbourhood of $x$. If you think otherwise, please give a description of  $\Gamma(V,\mathbb Z_X)$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thanks for your attention and patience. But if $x$ has no connected neighborhood, then a continuous function getting values in the sheaf can get different values at each connected component. Am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: Any  section of a **constant** sheaf like $\mathbb Z_X$  **must** necessarily only take one value in a sufficienlyt small neighbourhood of $x$, and the fact that there exists or not a connected neighbourhood of $x$ in $X$ is totally irrelevant. This is a consequence of the general procedure for associating a sheaf to a presheaf, the presheaf being the constant prsheaf with stalk $\mathbb Z$. The terminology "constant" applieed to both the presheaf and the associated sheaf is catastrophic; it  ensures that mistakes will be made when encountering these concepts for the first time! (...)

Comment: (continued)  Godement wisely called "simple" the sheaf associated to a constant presheaf but his terminology, alas, did not prevail.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Sorry for my insistence. However I'm not understanding it well, I've got that such neighborhooh exists because the stalks are the same (after applying the free functor), but if the space is totally disconnected and not discrete, for instance, I cannot see how you can guarantee that an arbitrary section cannot get different values at each connected component since the étale space is discrete. What's wrong in my thoughts?

Comment: The étale space is not discrete, but I understand your trouble. Can you describe the continuous functions from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Z$ endowed  with the discrete topology ? Do you think that a function  $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb Z$ which is constant on the connected components  of $\mathbb Q$ is necessarily continuous? If this is still not clear, I advise you to ask a new question.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Yes, any function. But I was trying to say that a connected set go to a connected set, so if the étale space ($\mathbb{Z} \times X$) is discrete (and now I'm seeing it's not because I was thinking in \mathbb{Z} only)  , then at a fixed connected component the function must attains only one value.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Sorry for pissing you off, but I still cannot get it. Think about a the plane and the constant sheaf over it, then pick a disk , goes up moving the disk along the fiber and incline that disk, this is a section and attains different values at each neighborhood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the theorem is true, because the presheaf and the sheaf have the same stalks, hence  by comparing some with a constant section such that they have the same value in the stalk one gets the neighborhood.

For the case of the sheaf $\mathbb{Z}_X$ where $X = \mathbb{R}^2$, the inclined disk (as said in the commentaries) is, in fact, not a section since this set in the étale space is not open (otherwise intersecting this with an horizontal open disk would be an open set, however it will be a line homeomorphic to a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$, an absurd).

**Why does the stalk APPARENTLY fail in converging to the integers?**

My confusion about the connectedness was given by the fact that the value of the sheaf in two disjoint disks is $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, when the space is tottaly disconnected, this does happens with every element of the basis (of open sets).

For instance, let $X = \mathbb{R}_S$ be the Sorgenfrey line and consider the constant sheaf over it. By letting $I_n = [0, 1/n[$, one can see that, at each $I_n$, the section can attains just a constant value, therefore $\mathbb{Z}_X (I_1)$ is at least $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$. Looking the way mentioned above, it looks like that, at the stalk (in $0$), the sheaf will not converges to $\mathbb{Z}$, since the diagram of the colimit will looks like a lot of arbitrary large products of the integers (at least as subgroups).

**Why does it, in fact, hold?**

However, fixing a section one can see that it must attains a fixed value in a neughborhood of the $0$ (because the constant function is a section), and then letting it "flows" throught the diagram, it´s easily seen that it will be an integer. Therefore , in fact, $(\mathbb{Z}_X)_0 = \mathbb{Z}$.